# How do I get my first input to be invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Basically, when I run the code if I put in an invalid answer for the first input it still continues onto the second input. I'm trying to get it if I put in an invalid answer for the first input It starts the loop again. (Sorry I'm very new)

```
play_again = "y"


# Collects both players name and gives error if not alphabet
while play_again == "y":
    def setup():enter code here
        playerOne = input("What is player 1's name: ")
        playerTwo = input("What is player 2's name: ")
        if playerOne.isalpha() == True and playerTwo.isalpha() == True:
            print("Valid names")
    
        else:
            print("Invalid name")
setup
```

Comment: If you don't want to run the second `input` if the first one is invalid, then you should test the `playerOne.isalpha()` condition _before_ calling `playerTwo = input(...)`.

Comment: You are defining the function inside `while loop` which is incorrect. Define function outside the for loop and call it in `for` loop. Using if-statement check if the name entered `isalpha()`.

Comment: How are you even getting the input prompt? You have an infinite loop simply defining the same function over and over again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking player one and two to be invalid at the same time after both are entered. Your code is ran from top to bottom and thus it takes both inputs before checking for being valid. You can fix this by substituting this.

```
playerOne = input(...)
if playerOne.isalpha():
   Print("name 1 is valid")
Else:
   Print("name is invalid please try again")
   # here you have some options you could end your program using exit() or put this method in a loop to keep asking for a new name pick one and add it in and it will repeat the check
player two = ... # you get the point just rewrite your previous code
```

Just ask if you need any help with any of the options I mentioned.

Comment: You're an amazing person :D :)